# Can executable size be optimized?

Tags: scheme, racket, executable, chicken-scheme

I have created executable of following code in Racket (choosing Racket and not GRacket):

```
#lang racket
(print "Hello World!")
```

It creates a tgz of 3.6 mb with an executable of 6.2 mb. This seems very large for this simplest program. Executable created by Chicken Scheme with same code `(print "Hello World!")` is of size 16984 bytes (16.6 kb) only.

I think I am missing something (possibly some optimization setting) while creating executable in Racket. How can this executable be made smaller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for [`raco exe`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe.html) recommends using as small a base language as possible. In this case, replace `#lang racket` with `#lang racket/base`. On my machine (Linux, Racket 6.8) that drops the executable size from 6.6M to 988K.

I was able to further reduce the size of the executable by running the demodularizer first. I saved the program as `hello.rkt` and ran

```
$ raco demod hello.rkt
$ raco exe -o hello hello_rkt_merged.zo
```

That produces an executable of 277K.

Comment: This solution used to work, but it doesn't anymore on the newer Racket 7.0

Comment: @logc thanks, I've created a bug report here: https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/2226

Comment: I tried to build it today with DrRacket 8.11[cs] on MacOS (Sonoma 14.1.1) and ended up having the size of 48 MB. I noticed that the size of the 'racket' executable itself is about the same size (not sure whether it is related - just find it suspicious).